# What does this expr do in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, expr

What does the following do exactly?

```
newProg=`expr "${newProg}" : ".* -> \(.*\)$"`   
if expr "x${newProg}" : 'x/' >/dev/null; then    
   prog="${newProg}"     
else    
    progdir=`dirname "${prog}"`   
    prog="${progdir}/${newProg}"    
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **first** line uses [`expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html) to:

- Match the value of `$newProg` against the [basic regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) `.* -> \(.*\)$` (anchored on both ends). That's anything with `->` in it.
- Set `newProg` to the part of the original value [matched by the capturing subexpression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_13_01) written in parentheses (the part after `->`).

The greedy matching semantics are such that this always captures and outputs the *last* such match, so there is never a `->` in the output.

This would, for example, parse the output of `ls -l` on a symlink to find the target (given well-behaved filenames, etc, usual caveats).

The **second** line uses `expr` again to check whether the new value of `newProg` begins with a `/`, i.e., it represents an absolute path.

In the case where it does, `prog` is just set to that value. Otherwise, `prog` is set to a computed relative path using `dirname` on `$prog`, a variable not defined in this snippet. The effect will presumably be to construct a path relative to that original location.

---

If you are only targeting a more capable shell or environment than pure POSIX, there is likely to be a more reliable way of doing this than `expr`. `readlink` is a very commonly-available command also, which would save on parsing `ls`.

Comment: +1. the only thing i'd add to that is that parsing the output of `ls` is **always** a bad idea, and using `expr` to parse ls is also inefficient and leads to ugly, difficult to read shell code....especially when every version of `test` aka `[` in existence has `-h` and/or `-L` options to test whether a file is a symlink or not.

Comment: A GNU readlink-based alternative to this could look like `[ -L "$newProg" ] && prog="$(readlink -m "$newprog")"` (1 line rather than 7).  And if $progdir is required (i.e. not just a temporary throwaway variable), append `&& progdir="$(dirname "$prog")"` to that line.   BTW, the `[ -L ... ] &&` test isn't required because running `readlink -m` on a non-symlink filename just returns that filename (with the full path).